# What Wrong with My Login Code that I did?

Tags: php, html

```
<h2>Login to Your Account</h2>
<form action='logins.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='username' value='Username ...' onclick='value=""'/><p />
    <input type='password' name='password' value='Password ...'   onclick='value=""'/><p />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login to my Account' />
</form>
```

Hello I am coding a simple form in Html which I would link to php but it don't processed to the page that the form should go. I have `login.php`, `register.php` and `Profile.php`, `dbconnect.php` Page.

Comment: Correct `logins.php` I think without the "s".

Comment: yes change it into login.php

Comment: you should pay attention before ask this kind of things here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are telling you have `login.php` page then you have done `logins.php` in the coding. Change it to the `login.php` so, you can process your site.

Change:

```
<form action='logins.php' method='POST'>
```

to:

```
<form action='login.php' method='POST'>
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy, It helped me a lot!